# Docker-compose new file to run 3 build commands

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My question is related to docker-compose, I need to create a new **docker-compose.yml** file only for this purpose: to run 3 docker build commands:

```
docker build --target node-sdk -f ./Dockerfile.sdk -t casino-node-sdk:12.16.3 .
```

How can I do this as I don't really have services to run, context or images?

**What I've tried**

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
  build:
    command: docker build --target node-sdk -f ./Dockerfile.sdk -t casino-node-sdk:12.16.3 .
    command: docker build --target node-sdk-ssh -f ./Dockerfile.sdk -t casino-node-sdk-ssh:12.16.3 .
    command: docker build --target node-run -f ./Dockerfile.sdk -t casino-node-run:12.16.3 .
```

**Error**

*Service build has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.*

Could you please help me with some ideas? I am a beginner at this.

Comment: Compose is principally about `docker run` type configuration; it can build images in support of that, but that's not its primary goal.  If the only thing you ever want to do is build images, a shell script or Makefile might be a better tool.

Comment: however how I can write my code in docker-compose.yml in order to do that to only run these 3 commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example: Let us assume, this is the content of the DockerFile you are having. Aliases are given as `base`, `dev` and `prod`.

## DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.6 as base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN pip install pipenv pip
COPY Pipfile ./
# some more common configuration...

FROM base as dev
RUN pipenv install --system --skip-lock --dev
ENV FLASK_ENV development
ENV FLASK_DEBUG 1

FROM base as prod
RUN pipenv install --system --skip-lock
ENV FLASK_ENV production
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app1:
    build:
      context: ./dir
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: base
  app2:
    build:
      context: ./dir
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: dev
  app3:
    build:
      context: ./dir
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: prod
```

Here `prod` is the stage alias that you are using in the DockerFile. It can be `base`, `dev`, `prod`.

Comment: I want to be able to run this "docker-compose build" - and this  onecommand to execute the bellow 3 commands. Sorry if my question was confusing.

Comment: I think you are trying to use stages in dockerfile and build each stage using compose.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think this is what you are looking for.